# Mensagem de erro: malloc: error for object 0x7: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++

Meu programa está dando esta mensagem de erro:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x7: pointer being freed was not
>   allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Alguém saberia por que?

O código é este:

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *entrada;
unsigned char isFile = 0x8;

struct tipo_seq {
    int tarefa;
    int valor;
};

struct tipo_multi {
    int adiantamento;
    int atraso;
    int total;
};

//variáveis globais
int numtar, nummaq;
int pjk[NMAX+1][MMAX+1], sjk[NMAX+1][MMAX+1], Cjk[NMAX+1][MMAX+1], dj[NMAX+1];
tipo_seq *sequencia = new tipo_seq;

//programa principal
int main()
{
    int j, k;
    string aux, diretorio;

    ifstream arquivo; //define variável tipo arquivo
    //ofstream saida;

    if ((dir =  opendir("/Users/heliofuchigami/Documents/FSJIT/benchmark/testes/")) != NULL){
        //lista todos os arquivos do diretório
        while ((entrada = readdir (dir)) != NULL){
            if (entrada->d_type == isFile){
                cout << entrada->d_name << endl;

                diretorio = "/Users/heliofuchigami/Documents/FSJIT/benchmark/testes/";
                diretorio += entrada->d_name;

                arquivo.open(diretorio, ios::in);

                //leitura dos dados do arquivo
                arquivo >> numtar;
                arquivo >> nummaq;

                for (j=1; j<=numtar; j++)
                    for (k=1; k<=nummaq; k++)
                        arquivo >> pjk[j][k];

                arquivo >> aux; //lê "SI"

                for (j=1; j<=numtar; j++)
                    for (k=1; k<=nummaq; k++)
                        arquivo >> sjk[j][k];

                arquivo >> aux; //lê "DUEDATE"

                for (j=1; j<=numtar; j++)
                    arquivo >> dj[j];

                arquivo.close();

                //inicializa variáveis
                for (j=0; j<=numtar; j++)
                    for (k=0; k<=nummaq; k++)
                        Cjk[j][k] = 0;

                //resolve o problema
                AlgoritmoColoniadeFormigas();

            }
        }

        closedir(dir);

    } else return EXIT_FAILURE;


    getchar();

    //libera memória das alocações dinâmicas
    delete [] sequencia;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Use um depurador para descobrir qual é a linha do erro e coloque aqui, por favor.

Comment: Difícil ter certeza sem acesso ao código completo mas dando uma olhada rápida da para ver que existe pelo menos um erro de memória já que você faz `tipo_seq *sequencia = new tipo_seq;` e depois libera utilizando `delete[]` que só deve ser utilizado quando se alocou um array de objetos.